# What's the parameter call for STDIN when you pipe things into echo or print?

Tags: bash, printing, pipe, echo

I have some text that I've created using a sting of pipes, and I'd like to further manipulate that using echo instead of awk.

Say that I have:

```
a chain | of | commands | producing |stream | of text
```

Yields:

```
line 1 text
line 2 text
line 3 text
```

But if I wanted to use echo to do something like this:

```
a chain | of | commands | producing |stream | of text | echo ${STDIN%text}
```

to cut off all text after where it says line, how would I reference that to get this expected result:

```
line 1 
line 2 
line 3
```

Comment: `echo` is simply not the right tool here. Any solution with `echo` will be convoluted and unnatural. sed or awk are best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tool like awk is best for your scenario :

```
a chain | of | commands | awk '{sub(/[[:blank:]]*text$/,"")}1'
```

`sub` by default acts on the whole record `$0` and will retain the number of spaces/tabs in the text retrieved.

---

<sup>Need more on awk? check [[ this ]](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html).</sup>

Comment: Also, anything that puts the output of a pipeline into a bash array will crash if the pipeline produces too much output.

Comment: @StephenC : I understand, that why i would provide an awk solution too.. :)

Comment: I guess this makes the most sense. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

While it would be handy to apply [parameter expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) such as `${var%text}` to *stdin* input, the shell doesn't support that - as the name suggests, parameter expansions are limited to *parameters (variables)*.

While you *could* pipe your command to a `while IFS= read -r line ...` loop and perform the expansion in the loop body on `${line}`, such an approach would be *slow* (and verbose).

Therefore, an *external utility* is the best choice here, such as `sed`:

```
cat <<<$'line 1 text\nline 2 text\nline 3 text' | sed 's/text$//'
```

<sup>The above `sed` command does exactly what your parameter expansion would do.

If you also want to trim the space before 'text': `sed 's/ text$//'`.

To trim a variable number of spaces, including none: `sed 's/ *text$//'`

To trim a variable number of spaces, but at least 1: `sed 's/ \{1,\}text$//'`</sup>

- (Basic) regular expression `text$` matches any line that ends in (`$`) `text`.
- `s/...//` then replaces the matched part with nothing (the empty string), effectively removing the `text` suffix.

---

[sjsam's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38669916/45375) shows an `awk`-based alternative.

Comment: The awk answer I guess makes the most sense. Thank you

Comment: @Tom: The `sed` solution will work equally well (and is slightly more concise), and performance will be similar, so in this particular case either solution is fine. Generally, `sed`'s strong suit is regex-based transformations (as in this case), whereas `awk` excels in field-based processing.